# Doctrine: Pass table name as parameter

Tags: parameters, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine on Symfony and need to safely pass a dynamic table name to an SQL query, since the "user" needs to be able to choose what backup table to restore values from.

My problem is that when I pass it as a parameter like in the following code, the table name is put in apostrophes which results in incorrect SQL syntax.

```
$sql = "UPDATE article a LEFT JOIN :restoretable rt USING (articleid) 
        SET a.stock = rt.stock";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['restoretable' => $restoretable]);
```

The old code used sprintf("UPDATE article a LEFT JOIN %s ...", $restoretable) and was prone to SQL injections.

My question therefore: How can I safely pass a table name (or row name, or anything else that can't be escaped with apostrophes) to my query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching about the possibilities PDO offers, along with those of Doctrine, I came to the following conclusing:
As stated by michal, it is not possible to pass a table name thrugh a Parameter, neither in Doctrine, nor in PDO. Verification of the validity has to be done manually.

Two of the possible solutions are as follows (there are also other solutions, but I'm describing here the ones I'm using now):

The **first option** is better, since the user input never gets close to the table. However, the table names have to be known at the time of coding. I use this to make a copy of an existing, known table.

```php
switch($userinput) {
    case "art": $tablename="article"; break;
    case "cus": $tablename="customer"; break;
    default: return false;
}

$newtablename = $tablename."_".date("YmdHis");

$conn = $this->em->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare(sprintf("CREATE TABLE %1\$s LIKE %2\$s; 
                                INSERT %1\$s SELECT * FROM %2\$s",
                                $newtablename,$tablename));
$stmt->execute();
```

**Option two** has the advantage that you can work with table names that are not explicitly known. However, the table name should not be completely random, and as such at least we should know the naming format. In my case it's `"article_".date("YmdHis")`.

We can now use a regular expression to check the user input for validity (in this case:

```php
$restoretable = $form->get('restoretable')->getData();
if (preg_match("/^article_[0-9]{14}$/i", $restoretable)) {
    $conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();

    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE article a LEFT JOIN %s rt USING (articleid) 
                        SET a.stock = rt.stock", $restoretable);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Just be sure to check your regular expression thoroughly.

Comment: Be very careful of course. To those who are accepting the tablename as user input, you must be very careful you're not open to SQL injection. The above scans the restoretable first with a carefully crafted REGEX, make sure you either do similar and be very in control of what comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution. There is no way to pass table name like You described.

```
    $metadata = $this->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata(MyEntityClass::class);
    $metadata->setPrimaryTable([
        'name' => 'myDynamicTableName'
    ]);

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    $result = $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

but in this example You will need to know what is the table name and entity class name.

Regarding table name and SQL injections. The best if table name will contains only English alphabets and underscore. And thats it.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/security.html#user-input-and-doctrine-orm
for more info about insecured dql queries.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not working with enitities in my backup table and mass updates cannot be done through the query builder. I came up with another solution in the meantime though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna use DQL/SQL statements, and you really need to use identifiers, you might as well use:

```php
$sometablename = $connection->quoteIdentifier('sometablename');
```

So something like:

```php
$table = $entityManager->getConnection()->quoteIdentifier('sometable');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM $table`;
```

Would end up:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `sometable`;
```

But always be careful of what comes in. Even if it's not SQL Injection, someone could always do "information_schema" or a different table you weren't expecting.